# Why is that the 'blocks count' is always in multiples of 192?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, nodes, rinkeby, blocks

I'm running light node client for rinkeby using command:

`geth --rinkeby --syncmode=light --rpc --rpcapi personal,db,net,eth,web3`

The terminal runs continuously and I don't quit it when I close the laptop monitor. When the laptop is hibernated (monitor is closed), the node stops syncing. And when I resume the laptop (re-open the monitor), the node starts syncing.

While importing the 'new block headers', the 'blocks *count*' is always in multiples of 192 (Example: `count=192 | count=1344 | count=576`), until full import is done.

Why in multiples of 192? Why not 50 or 100?

Log trace:

`INFO [06-03|01:29:38] Imported new block headers               count=1   elapsed=75.603ms  number=2393660 hash=12f7ae…f39bd4 ignored=0
INFO [06-03|01:29:38] Imported new block headers               count=0   elapsed=129.563µs number=2393660 hash=12f7ae…f39bd4 ignored=1
INFO [06-03|13:35:03] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=330.559ms number=2393852 hash=609755…460a4e ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:35:04] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=462.307ms number=2394044 hash=320d10…133b2e ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:35:05] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=771.555ms number=2394236 hash=f0e2f4…32160b ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:35:08] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=2.406s    number=2394428 hash=8df410…bff82b ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:35:09] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=1.123s    number=2394620 hash=3b472e…304d40 ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:35:11] Imported new block headers               count=1344 elapsed=1.589s    number=2395964 hash=f11335…bdb486 ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:35:16] Imported new block headers               count=576  elapsed=5.749s    number=2396540 hash=83b56f…2d34b7 ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:35:17] Imported new block headers               count=22   elapsed=88.833ms  number=2396562 hash=4a2013…e490b5 ignored=0
INFO [06-03|13:37:08] Imported new block headers               count=8    elapsed=46.601ms  number=2396570 hash=14f9a5…9bf85e ignored=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why in multiples of 192?

It's just [a constant](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/84f8c0cc1fbe1ab9c128555392a82ba609820fef/eth/downloader/downloader.go#L42).

```
MaxHeaderFetch  = 192 // Amount of block headers to be fetched per retrieval request
```

> Why not 50 or 100?

Because 50 and 100 isn't an octal. 
The [octal numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), or oct for short, is the base-8 number system, and uses the digits 0 to 7. The oct system used widely in CS.

Comment: Thanks! By looking at the other [constants] (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/84f8c0cc1fbe1ab9c128555392a82ba609820fef/eth/downloader/downloader.go#L40) defined, like (`MaxHashFetch    = 512` and  `MaxBlockFetch = 128`), I assume that it's in multiples of '8'. Correct?

Comment: yes, bytes must be aligned.